# change specific indexes in string to same value python

Tags: python, string, file-io

**Goal**

Reading in a massive binary file approx size 1.3GB and change certain bits and then writing it back to a separate file (cannot modify original file).

**Method**

When I read in the binary file it gets stored in a massive string encoded in hex format which is immutable since I am using python.

My algorithm loops through the entire file and stores in a list all the indexes of the string that need to be modified. The catch is that all the indexes in the string need to be modified to the same value. I cannot do this in place due to immutable nature. I cannot convert this into a list of chars because that blows up my memory constraints and takes a hell lot of time. The viable thing to do is to store it in a separate string, but due to the immutable nature I have to make a ton of string objects and keep on concatenating to them.

I used some ideas from https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/ however it doesn't give me a good performance. Any ideas, the goal is to copy an existing super long string exactly into another except for certain placeholders determined by the values in the index List ?

Comment: The replacements are the same size of the original? I so you can seek the file position and write in place on the disk.

Comment: You say "writing it back", but in the comment to my answer say "constraint is to not change the original file". That's a contradiction.

Comment: question edited- sorry for ambiguity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, to be honest, you shouldn't be reading your file into a string. You shouldn't especially be writing anything but the bytes you actually change.
That is just a waste of resources, since you only seem to be reading linearly through the file, noting the down the places that need to be modified.

On all OSes with some level of mmap support (that is, Unixes, among them Linux, OS X, *BSD and other OSes like Windows), you can use [Python's `mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module to just open the file in read/write mode, scan through it and edit it in place, without the need to ever load it to RAM completely and then write it back out. Stupid example, converting all 12-valued bytes by something position-dependent:

Note: this code is mine, and not MIT-licensed. It's for text-enhancement purposes and thus covered by CC-by-SA. Thanks SE for making this stupid statement necessary.

```
import mmap
with open("infilename", "r") as in_f:
  in_view = mmap.mmap(in_f.fileno(), 0) ##length = 0: complete file mapping
  length = in_view.size()
  with open("outfilename", "w") as out_f
    out_view = mmap.mmap(out_f.fileno(), length)
    for i in range(length):
       if in_view[i] == 12:
         out_view[i] = in_view[i] + i % 10
       else:
         out_view[i] = in_view[i]
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, however the constraint is that I cannot modify the input file , I need to write it out into a separate file format that will link into another process. So changing it in memory won't do me good. Also some of the input files are read only and I don't even have the permission to mmap them, any other suggestions ?

Comment: you can still mmap them readonly, and copy the contents over to a second, writeonly mmaped file. That's what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

What about slicing the string, modify each slice, write it back on the disk before moving on to the next slice? Too intensive for the disk?

Comment: I will actually try that out, my inherent assumption to that is going to disk will slow program down drastically. But might be interesting to see the actual performance tradeoff.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to leave a comment to start the discussion but I don't have enough reputation...